# Where to put node folder for node.js install?

Tags: macos, node.js, installation

It's currently in the directory:
/Users/myusername/node

but I feel like it should be closer to root?  Maybe in /Developer? I'm having trouble finding an other advice online.  I'm on macosx lion right now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're on Mac OS X you can use homebrew to manage the installation of a number of things that have recipes.  Node.js is one of them.

[Link](https://brew.sh/)

Once homebrew is installed and up to date you can simply run a command like the following.

```
brew install node.js
```

Comment: Make sure that it's the latest version (0.6.15).

Answer (score 14):

There is also now a Macintosh(or Windows) installer available for current releases(0.6.18 currently the latest at time of this writing).  The universal .pkg installer will handle the everything for you so you don't need to worry about it :-)

If you want to know where the install ends up, I recently installed v0.6.17 on OSX Lion 10.7.4 and it looks like most of the files are under `/usr/local/`.  Shell commands in `/usr/local/bin/`.  Global node_modules and npm in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`.

Hope that helps!